# When using Hover to change the text color , it only works when screen minimizes

Tags: css

So , i have a button whose text color i want to change when hover over it , however it only changes the text color when screen minimizes

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 career">
        <button>
            <strong>Student Exploring careers</strong>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.career button{
    margin-top:5%;
   /*letter-spacing: 1px;*/
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 }

.career button:hover{
    color:#000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: in wich div you placed the button?

Comment: Can you show us the entire code?

Comment: your code is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is working but here in the code you shared its the color youre choosing

```css
 button{
    margin-top:5%;
   /*letter-spacing: 1px;*/
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 button:hover{
    color:red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 career">
        <button>
            <strong>Student Exploring careers</strong>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works fine  with the color as well but only when the screen minimizes

Comment: you can use !important

Comment: to override the css

Comment: i guess i figured it out , might be some other code is messing up with it

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 button_cont">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary example_a">Primary</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS code.

```
.example_a {
            color: #fff !important;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background: #ed3330;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: none;
            }
            .example_a:hover {
background: #434343;
letter-spacing: 1px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
box-shadow: 5px 40px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
button{
    margin-top:5%;
   /*letter-spacing: 1px;*/
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 }

 button:hover{
    color:red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 career">
        <button>
            <strong>Student Exploring careers</strong>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```